# Unable to access my own websites from our home

Tags: website

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but i'm gonna have a shot at it.

I host a couple of websites with a webhost in the Netherlands. For a couple of days now, i've been unable to connect to them from my home network. When using tracert in the cmd screen, i'm getting a timeout after about 4-5 hops.

It seems fine accessing the website from anywhere, except my home network. Other PC's around the house also fail to open the websites. I've tried 'flushing my DNS' as seen in some other topics, but to no avail just yet.

One of the websites: http://bit.ly/1hbqs4J

I've contacted my host about it as well, but no response yet. Trying to take control of the situation myself now for as much as I can.

Regards,
Dave

Comment: This looks like a problem of routing between your home Internet connection and your hosting server. It won't be something that the hosting company can do anything about, and it's probably outside your own control. Talk to the ISP that provides your Internet connection to your home.

Answer (score 1):

could check if the dns server is set up correctly.  Try a ping to the site & see if this works.  If the ping command should fail, you could change to google's dns server.  8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

```
me $ host smartphonehandschoenen.nl
smartphonehandschoenen.nl has address 93.184.96.77
smartphonehandschoenen.nl mail is handled by 10 mail.smartphonehandschoenen.nl.
me $ ping -c5  93.184.96.77
PING 93.184.96.77 (93.184.96.77) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.96.77: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.96.77: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.96.77: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=145 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.96.77: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=145 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.96.77: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=144 ms

--- 93.184.96.77 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 144.483/144.947/145.650/0.431 ms
me $
```